# Cómo puedo obtener un código de autentificación mediante POST

Tags: angular

Necesito saber cómo obtener mediante código el "access_token" que me devuelve por post esta petición.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Había pensado en incluir una función en un servicio similar a esta:

```
renovamos(){

const headers = new HttpHeaders({
grant_type: 'client_credentials',
client_id: '290daa79bf08476c9bdd5e870bc238e8',
client_secret: 'bf2c6317dd974de3b582df281122a509'


});




return this.http.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',body, {headers});

}
```

Peor no funciona, cuál es la forma adecuada de hacerlo?

Finalmente he puesto la función del servicio:

```
 login(): Observable<any> {

  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: '290daa79bf08476c9bdd5e870bc238e8',
    client_secret: 'bf2c6317dd974de3b582df281122a509'
    });

  // Headers...
  return this.http.post<any>('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {headers});
```

Pero me devuelve un error 415:

```
POST https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token 415
```

core.js:6014 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 415, statusText: "OK", url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", ok: false, …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
status: 415
statusText: "OK"
url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure response for https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token: 415 OK"
error: {error: "server_error"}
**proto**: HttpResponseBase

Answer (score 1):

El método **POST** retorna un `Observable<...>`, para leer la data que necesitas solo debes suscribirte a este.

Ejemplo:

Paso 1. Método de login

```
login(): Observable<any> {
    // Headers...
    return this.http.post<any>('https://website/api/token', {headers});
  }
```

Paso 2. Recibir la data desde tu componente

```
this.miServicio.login().subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
```

Verás en consola toda la información que te retorna ese endpoint. Si quieres también, puedes convertir a promesa el método `login` y para recibir la data sustituyes el `subscribe` por el **then** en el componente.

Comment: Ah..ok. Muchas gracias!

Es decir que lo que devuelve la función es un observable por lo que veo. Al poner el "any" significa que es de cualquier tipo?

He hecho peticiones a servicios con GET en funciones de ese mismo servicio y luego me he subscrito a ellas para recuperar el valor que devuelven, peor no he tenido que poner nada de "Observable" al declarar la función en el servicio, GET y POST funcionan distinto?

Comment: @casiopea2000 Por defecto las llamadas `http` retornan un `Observable`. El `any` lo he puesto para indicar que retorna cualquier tipo, pero, puedes ponerle el tipo que quieras, ya sea `string`, alguna interfaz, etc.. o simplemente no indicar que ese método retorna algo. Esto es opcional pero es buena práctica siempre indicar qué retorna un método y de qué tipo. Si alguien más revisa tu código no sabrá rápidamente si un método retorna algo o no, de qué tipo sería, etc... otra ventaja es que al llamar a esos métodos, tu IDE sabrá que opciones ofrecerte para auto-completado.

Comment: Ok, Muchas gracias.

Comment: Una pregunta más

Comment: He editado la pregunta añadiendo el error 415 que me da después de modificar el la función

Comment: @casiopea2000 El error que presentas quiere decir que el formato/payload que le estas enviando no es soportado o no es el correcto. Tu pregunta original era sobre cómo obtener la data que te retorna un endpoint y mi respuesta ataca esa duda. Ahora tienes un problema diferente, debes leer la documentación de spotify sobre cómo obtener/enviar el token correctamente. Este problema es totalmente diferente a lo que dice tu pregunta inicial, por lo tanto, te recomiendo abrir otro hilo específicamente para este nuevo problema que presentas.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias de todas formas. Me has ayudado mucho.

Comment: @casiopea2000 Estamos para ayudar. Si al final mi respuesta te ha servido para entender cómo obtener el valor de un request, no olvides votarla o marcarla como respuesta seleccionada, podrá ayudar a futuros usuarios con la misma duda a identificar rápidamente la solución. Saludos.

Comment: Ok, cómo voto la respuesta?

Comment: @casiopea2000 si tienes la reputación suficiente, en mi respuesta al lado izquierdo te aparecen botones para votar positivamente o negativamente la solución proporcionada.

Comment: En el punto 2 de esa documentación del API me dice que cómo acceder: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#2-have-your-application-request-refresh-and-access-tokens-spotify-returns-access-and-refresh-tokens    pero no sé cómo implementarlo en el código.

Comment: @casiopea2000 Intenta hacerlo paso a paso como dice ahí. Si no lo logras, abre otro hilo en el foro para pedir ayuda con eso específicamente y con gusto los usuarios podrán ayudarte.